# Why don't pipe() or apply() work properly on this pandas groupby?

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, pipe, apply

I have DataFrame with columns `col1, col2, col3`. I want to create another `col4` which contains `col2[n+3]/col2-1` for each group in `col1` separately:

```
|col1 | col2 | col3|
|-----|------|-----|    
|  A  |  2   |  4  |
|  A  |  4   |  5  | 
|  A  |  7   |  7  | 
|  A  |  3   |  8  | 
|  A  |  7   |  3  | 
|  B  |  8   |  9  |
|  B  |  10  |  10 | 
|  B  |  8   |  9  |
|  B  |  20  |  15 |
```

The output should be:

```
|col1 | col2 | col3| col4|
|-----|------|-----|-----|    
|  A  |    2 |   4 |  0.5|  # (3/2-1)
|  A  |    4 |   5 | 0.75|  # (7/4-1)
|  A  |    7 |   7 |  NA |
|  A  |    3 |   8 |  NA |
|  A  |    7 |   3 |  NA |
|  B  |    8 |   9 | 1.5 |
|  B  |   10 |  10 |  NA |
|  B  |    8 |  9  |  NA |
|  B  |   20 |  15 |  NA |
```

My code is:

```
df['col4']= df.groupby('col1').apply(lambda x: x['col2'].shift(-3)/x['col2']-1)
```

which results in `col4` with all entries 'NA'.

I also tried:

```
df['col4']= df.groupby('col1').pipe(lambda x: x['col2'].shift(-3)/x['col2']-1)
```

which ignores groups 'A' and 'B' and results in:

```
|col1 | col2 | col3| col4  |
|-----|------|-----|-------|      
|  A  |  2   |  4  | 0.5   |
|  A  |  4   |  5  | 0.75  |
|  A  |  7   |  7  | 0.1428|
|  A  |  3   |  8  | 2.33  |
|  A  |  7   |  3  | 0.1428|
|  B  |  8   |  9  | 1.5   |
|  B  | 10   | 10  | NA    |
|  B  |  8   |  9  | NA    |
|  B  | 20   | 15  | NA    |
```

Does anyone know how to do this task or fix my code?

Comment: [pandas issue #31063: groupby() apply() gets the shape wrong](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31063) in the case where i) The groupby key happens to have a unique value ii) The apply function takes a DataFrame and returns a Series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df['col4'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(lambda x: x.shift(-3)) / df['col2'] - 1
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2  col3  col4
0    A     2     4  0.50
1    A     4     5  0.75
2    A     7     7   NaN
3    A     3     8   NaN
4    A     7     3   NaN
5    B     8     9  1.50
6    B    10    10   NaN
7    B     8     9   NaN
8    B    20    15   NaN
```

Use `transform` to shift your 'col2' within each group then divide by 'col2' and subtract 1.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works but I still don't understand why pipe did not work.

Comment: Your pipe use here is very unconventional and I am not sure you can get it work as if you are thinking.  This solution a better fit for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Your groupby with apply returns the correct series but then you will have some problems joining this back to the original dataframe.  Using transform is a better solution.

Comment: Can you explain why the OP's use of `pipe` is unconventional (is it only the `.shift(-3)`)? This is essentially a code-only answer too specific to one use-case, hence not a reusable resource; please add some explanation.